# Building CSW query to discover available products in GeoNetwork

Tags: geonetwork, csw

My task is to implement data discovery and download starting from a CSW catalogue based on GeoNetwork.  I got into the GetCapabilities of it but I do not understand how to move from the metadata catalogue of CSW to the download operation.

Which is the CSW type of query to build to discover the available products?

Comment: As it stands I think your question would benefit from being heavily revised to try and make what you are asking clearer.  I recommend reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 for tips on how to structure a good question.

Comment: Not CSW, but with GeoNetwork if you want to get a list of all available records, another thing you can do is use the sitemap ~ ..://your-server/metadata/srv/eng/portal.sitemap.

Answer (score 2):

Typically you would use the CSW GetRecords operation, which allows to to filter on location, properties, and sorting/paging.  You can find numerous examples (for any CSW) from the [pycsw tests](https://github.com/geopython/pycsw/tree/master/tests/functionaltests/suites/default/post).

In addition, checkout the sample pycsw [viewer](http://demo.pycsw.org/viewer/) for an example application.  Be sure to view the HTML source and enable to web console to see client/server communication of the CSW request/response patterns.